# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java?

Tags: java

I try to run this java program which returns a webpage in my webroot folder

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WebServer {

    static ServerSocket requestListener;
    static Socket requestHandler;
    static Scanner requestReader, pageReader;
    static DataOutputStream pageWriter;
    static String HTTPMessage;
    static String requestedFile;
    public static int HTTP_PORT = 12346;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            requestListener = new ServerSocket(HTTP_PORT);

            System.out.println("Waiting For IE to request a page:");
            requestHandler = requestListener.accept();
            System.out.println("Page Requested: Request Header:");

            requestReader = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
                    requestHandler.getInputStream()));
//THis is the part where its throwing the error

            int lineCount = 0;
            do {

                lineCount++; // This will be used later
                HTTPMessage = requestReader.next();
                System.out.println(HTTPMessage);
                if (lineCount == 1) {
                    requestedFile = "WebRoot\\"
                            + HTTPMessage.substring(5,
                                    HTTPMessage.indexOf("HTTP/1.1") - 1);
                    requestedFile = requestedFile.trim();
                }

                // localhost:12346/default.htm
                // HTTPMessage = requestReader.nextLine();
                pageReader = new Scanner(new File(requestedFile));
                pageWriter = new DataOutputStream(
                        requestHandler.getOutputStream());
                while (pageReader.hasNext()) {
                    String s = pageReader.nextLine();
                    // System.out.println(s);
                    pageWriter.writeBytes(s);
                }
                // Tells the Browser we’re done sending
                pageReader.close();
                pageWriter.close();
                requestHandler.close();

            } while (HTTPMessage.length() != 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.out.println("\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and I get this error message. I am supposed to get a webpage in IE but all I get this error message.

Waiting For IE to request a page:

```
Page Requested: Request Header:
GET
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -7
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at WebServer.main(WebServer.java:39)
```

Comment: Are you asking what `StringIndexOutOfBounds` represents, or why your code is throwing this exception? The sort-of-short answer is that somewhere your code is referencing a string with an index of `-7` and you need to debug where this is happening. Any chance it's happening here: `HTTPMessage.indexOf("HTTP/1.1") - 1)` - have you checked the responses coming into this code? Seems like you're expecting to find that substring and it's not actually in the input?

Comment: I am trying to extract the requested page title from http header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is being thrown because the String '**HTTPMessage**' does not contain the string 'HTTP/1.1'. Hence

```
HTTPMessage.indexOf("HTTP/1.1")  => returns -1
```

So inside yoour substring function this is whats getting passed :

```
 HTTPMessage.substring(5, -2);
```

Hence the error.

To solve this error, you should first try to check if HTTPMessage contains the required string and then try to compute the substring. Make the following change :

```
 if (lineCount == 1 && HTTPMessage.indexOf("HTTP/1.1") != -1) {
                requestedFile = "WebRoot\\"
                        + HTTPMessage.substring(5,
                                HTTPMessage.indexOf("HTTP/1.1") - 1);
                requestedFile = requestedFile.trim();
  }
```